# Algorithm problem finding Armstrong number in Dart language

Tags: dart

This is my code and I'm trying to write a function in dart language that finds an Armstrong number.

```
bool isArmstrongNumber(String number){

  final tempNumber = BigInt.parse(number);
  var totalNumber = BigInt.from(0);
  

  for(int i = 0;i<number.length;i++){
    int tempValue = int.parse(number[i]);

     totalNumber +=  BigInt.from(pow(tempValue, number.length));
    
  }
```

its works fine when i use small numbers like '9926315' .but
when i tried big numbers like
'115132219018763992565095597973971522401' its doesnt work. i saw that in debug mode, the numbers turns minus after 9. loop but i dont know why. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `pow(tempValue, number.length)` ends up generating numbers that is too large to fit in Dart integer (which are a signed long). So when you later on try use that number, you get the wrong result.

If you instead convert the `tempValue` into a BigInt, you can then call `pow` on it directly with the exponent and prevent the issue:

```dart
bool isArmstrongNumber(String number) {
  var totalNumber = BigInt.from(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    int tempValue = int.parse(number[i]);

    totalNumber += BigInt.from(tempValue).pow(number.length);
  }

  return totalNumber.toString() == number;
}

void main() {
  print(isArmstrongNumber('115132219018763992565095597973971522401')); // true
}
```